# Promela atomic propositions for multiple proctype instances

Tags: verification, spin, promela, model-checking

I was wondering how to write never claims that stand for all instances of a proctype. For example if I have the following proposition:

```
#define c (camera_node[SomePid]:start_publishing == 0)
```

Now if I instantiate 5 instances of the `camera_node` how can I create an atomic proposition checking if `start_publishing` is equal to zero for all of these 5 instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it isn't the most beautiful, but I've done this sort of thing in the past.  (Note: this code probably isn't proper Promela but you get the point)

```
#define NUMBER_OF_CAMERA_NODES  5

pid_t  cameraPids [NUMBER_OF_CAMERA_NODES];
byte_t cameraPidIndex = 0

active [NUMBER_OF_CAMERA_NODES] proctype cameraTask () {
  atomic { cameraPids[cameraPidIndex++] = _pid }
  // ...
}

#define cameraCheck( index ) (0 == camera_node[cameraPids[(index)]]:start_publishing)

#define checkAllCameras  (cameraCheck(0) && cameraCheck(1) && ...)
```

Comment: Well that was a bit too late to include it it my dissertation, but still great to know! : ) Thanks